# Twilio Studio HTTP request

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I have been working with Twilio Studio trying to build this IVR tree. I need a few requests that will go back to my main platform to check the caller_id of the line calling in and to verify_employee pin etc after the caller_id is verified.

I know there is an HTTP request widget that I can use to hit the endpoints on the main platform. But I am running into the issue where it's validating the number that's inputed. The person calling in will get verified then have to enter the 3 provider pin and 4 employee number. Right now I can input anything and it will go through onto the next option. Anything I can do to validate the numbers against the endpoint? or maybe I am just doing my tree wrong.

Off of the trigger I am using a http request to check the caller id of the person calling in. Then using a gather input widget to gather the pin #'s then using that to call the verify employee http request.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How have you got this set up so far? I would be making the HTTP request and then using a Split widget to do different things based on the response from the request.

Comment: Yea, I have got this set up a few days ago. Thanks for replying! Twilio is hard to get a hold of sometimes as far as help. Do you have any good resources for contacts?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. For questions like this, getting in touch with [support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) is one way to ask questions, as is posting here on Stack Overflow (I tend to look out for questions here, though it's sometimes hard to keep up).

Answer (score 0):

The Twilio `Split Widget` based on the http response (and one more
later, based on the user input for their code...) should do the job.